# Setting file permissions on a web server

Tags: php, html

Need a bit of clarification on this.

I have a folder in my web server that will contain sensitive information that no one should be able to read. My script currently does this:

makes the folder with 0777 permission and places an image in that folder

I have a second script that does this:

pulls that image from that specific folder, and shows it to the user

However, right now if the user knew the exact name of the parent folder, they can just type it in their browser and see all the images contained in that folder, like: *www.testsite/test/images*

What file permission can I use instead of 0777, that will allow these two scripst to write in and read in to the folder, WITHOUT allowing anyone to view the contents of the folder when typing it in their browser?

Comment: Why would you set it to `000`? Then **no-one** would be able to read it. Is that intentional? Are you sure you don't simply want `700`?

Comment: Sorry, I left out some key information, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're worried about a user typing in `/test/images/` into the URL bar, and seeing the directory listing containing your secret file.

Setting a `chmod` of `000` would mean that **neither** of your scripts (nor you) would be able to access the folder.

In my opinion, you'd be far better off using `.htaccess` with `deny from all`. This will make it so that you cannot 'open' any file in that folder, though you can still include them in PHP.

Alternatively, you may opt for creating an `index.php` in your `/images/` folder, and setting an automatic redirect with `header('Location: /')`. This way a user wouldn't be able to see the directory listing.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: that index.php in the images folder is genius! 

just to clarify, the folder will automatically call upon the index.php script right? and all I would have to put in there is the redirect?

Thank you that did help! pretty cool idea, will try that out!

Comment: Yes; navigating to a folder will automatically attempt to look for the relevant index there - `.index.html`, `index.php`, etc. If the only file there is `index.php`, it will **automatically** display `.index.php` for the user, and thus they will automatically get directed. They will never see the directory listing, nor will there be any trace of it in any of the logs.

Comment: What about this example:

inside the /test/images, we have /images/1/305, /images/2/305, the user can still add those in their url and visit those folders, even though i have index.php redirecting them inside the images folder

how do I redirect them for each subfolder inside the images folder? best way would be with file permissoin right?

Comment: Yes, if you have multiple sub-folders, then **each** folder will need it's own index in that regard. You could also write an `.htaccess` rule to automatically redirect based on certain folder conditions.

Comment: does the .htaccess file sit inside the parent folder which would affect all its children folders?

Comment: `.htaccess` sits in the `root`. You can have more than one, but the 'root' one is essentially doing all the work. More info on that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892921).